# Solving congruence how to ensure that I always have the base answer

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am practising solving congruence and have found that my method doesn't always give me the lowest possible answer. I assume the process below would find the lowest possible answer, but I checked and 2 is the lowest. What step am I missing in this process:

---

3(2x)≡3(1)(mod 9)

2x≡1 (mod 9)

The closes value to 0 by adding/subtracting 9 to 1 is -8

```
            2x≡-8 (mod 10)
```

Then, we divide by 2:

```
            x≡-4 (mod 9)
```

Finally, since we cannot have a negative, we need to keep adding by 9 until we get a positive integer:

```
        x≡5 (mod 9)
```

This only gives us one solution, and there are 3 in total. We keep adding three to give us our other two answers:

x≡5 (mod 9)

x≡8 (mod 9)

x≡11 (mod 9)

---

How would I have known that it starts at 2 and not 5?

Comment: $3(2x)\equiv3(1)\pmod9\iff2x\equiv1\color{blue}{\equiv4}\pmod{\color\red3}$; also, you could see $11-9=2$

Comment: To obtain an *equivalent* congruence you need to cancel $\:\!\color{#c00}3\:\!$ from the $\rm\color{#c00}{modulus}$ too - see the congruence cancellation rule in the linked dupe. **Or**, said in equivalent divisibility language $\,\color{#0a0}3\cdot \color{#c00}3\mid \color{#c00}3\:\!(2x\!-\!1)\iff \color{#0a0}3\mid 2x\!-\!1,\,$ by cancelling $\,\color{#c00}3\ \ $